Allow users with the ability to Vote To Delete to always see how many delete votes an answer or closed question has
Users with more than 10,000 reputation on sites with "Full" reputation requirements and 2,000 reputation on sites with "Beta" reputation requirements have the "Access to Moderation Tools" privilege. Amongst other things, those users can see how many "Delete" votes a post has. On answers, users can only see that if the post scores -1 or lower. As well, on closed questions, users between 10k-20k reputation (2k-4k on beta reputation levels) cannot see delete votes if the post has not been closed for at least 2 days.
This sometimes annoying, because, occasionally (for whatever reason), a post attracts delete vote(s) while not being negatively scored. If the post is only at a score of 0, then you can downvote it, reload, and see how many delete votes the post has, and then remove your downvote (or keep it if the post deserves it), but this is rather annoying to do. In addition, Tinkeringbell has indicated that this workaround is a breach of the Code of Conduct. If the post scores at 1 or above, then there is nothing you can do at all (unless the you happen to be one of the upvoters and your vote isn't locked, but even so at 2 or above the same issue happens) to see how many delete votes the post has (unless you start looking in the post's history or the /tools area). And, of course, for closed questions that were closed less than 2 days ago, there's nothing you can do but wait.
I don't see the benefit to hiding how many delete votes an answer has just because it's not negatively scored or a question because it was recently closed. If a user has enough reputation that they are trusted to actually vote to delete a post, shouldn't they be trusted to know if there are delete votes and how many delete votes there?
Could users with the ability to Vote To Delete be allowed see always see how many delete votes an answer or closed question has?

Maybe I'm missing it, but what would the use of this be, except 'satisfying curiosity'? What difference would being able to see this make to whether or not a post warrants a downvote/delete vote? Also, to me, downvoting just to see if there are delete votes, already sounds like you're not voting for the content of the post, which is technically already a CoC breach, a disruptive use of tooling. You should probably refrain from that from now on.

@Tinkeringbell What is the purpose of ever allowing users to see delete votes? If you want I’ll stop doing that but I don’t see how it’s disruptive if I immediately (10 seconds) revert the vote (or keep it if I feel the post deserves a downvote, but then that’s just regular downvoting at that point)

This is consistent with other elements in Stack Exchange, for example close votes: when we can't close a question we don't see a link to close it, hence as a result we don't see how many pending close votes it has, and we can't retract our close vote, if it exists. (At least not via the site interface.)
I think this is a fine and proper design, as there's no point seeing action you can't perform.
What you suggest is splitting the pending votes count from the actual action, and while this is legit request of course, and perhaps "nice to have" for some, I don't think it's useful enough to add a new design element for everyone.
I'm pretty sure such thing can be read via the API, thus can be added with a userscript, for those interested.

The only time (that I'm aware of) when you can't close a question is because its already closed, and hence there can't be any pending close votes

@Starship, I believe you are also not allowed to cast a close-vote if you previously voted to close a question and it subsequently got re-opened (to avoid a close-reopen cycle if two groups of 3/5 people disagree on whether a Q should be closed or not).

@BartvanIngenSchenau I'm pretty sure it's just you need to wait 2-3 weeks

@Starship No, that permanently bars you from voting to close the question. You're also permanently barred if you retracted your close vote.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Oh okay. Is that also true of delete votes? Anyways a close-reopen cycle is also not really similar to the scenario I'm talking about with delete votes

@Starship Yes, the same is true of delete votes - if you vote to delete a post and it's undeleted, you are barred from voting to delete again, and also if you retracted your vote to delete.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Anyways, that it a pretty rare case. An answer with a score over -1 or a closed question closed less than 2 days ago is not.

@Starship actually when you voted to close already you still see the close link and can click it, where you'll see you can't vote to close again so indeed not what I mean in the answer. I mean cases like locked question, and a question can be locked while still having pending close votes on it.
